# How to make a top layer LinearLayout clickable through its children?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have built a series of LinearLayouts on top of each other and used weightSum to split parts of the screen up. [I made this illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnH6I.jpg) to show what I'm looking to make happen...

What is happening is the orange layout is clickable, however it is only clickable in that *very* thin line where it is after the red and before the green & blue. What I'd like to do is make it so even if I click blue or green, so long as it is in the bounds of orange, orange is pressed. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Simple Solution to this would be setting the `onClick` argument of the `LinearLayout` to `false`

And Here is a Simple Code Example. From this, you can see that wherever you may touch on the screen, It's going to activate that `Toast`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.android.test.MainActivity"
        android:onClick="youClicked">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello"
                    android:textSize="80sp"
                    android:clickable="false"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

To Brief, set the `onClick` parameter of the Child `LinearLayout` to `false`.